# How can I convert from Gwei to Wei or Ether using web3py

Tags: web3.py

I know there is `web3.fromWei('myamount','ether')` to convert from `Wei` to `Ether`.

But what if I have only the `Gwei` amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind importing another library, [Brownie](https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/brownie)'s [Wei](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-brownie.html#brownie.convert.Wei) class makes it very simple to get from `gwei` to `wei`:

```py
>>> from brownie import Wei
>>> Wei("1 gwei")
1000000000
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

def covert(amount):
    #: Convert gwei to wei
    wei_amount = Decimal(amount) * (Decimal(10) ** 9)  # Gigaweis are billions
    eth_amount = web3.fromWei(wei_amount,'ether')
    return wei_amount, eth_amount
```